# Multiple testing adjustment for stepwise model selection

Tags: model, logistic-regression, feature-selection, coefficients, bonferroni

I am trying to construct a regression model with the stepwise procedure. I wonder given the relatively high number of variables (about 50 clinical variables) I am testing if it would be better to adjust for multiple testing (Bonferroni for example ?) Do you have any idea, recommendation of paper or any other reference? Thank you ! I tried to find some references online